# Sorting postgresql database dump (pg_dump)

Tags: php, linux, postgresql, sorting, pg-dump

I am creating to pg_dumps, DUMP1 and DUMP2.

DUMP1 and DUMP2 are exactly the same, except DUMP2 was dumped in REVERSE order of DUMP1.

Is there anyway that I can sort the two DUMPS so that the two DUMP files are exactly the same (when using a diff)?

I am using PHP and linux. I tried using "sort" in linux, but that does not work...

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[From your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178907/postgres-pg-dump-dumps-database-in-a-different-order-every-time/2179608), I assume that what you are really trying to do is compare to databases to see if they are they same including the data.

[As we saw there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178907/postgres-pg-dump-dumps-database-in-a-different-order-every-time/2179304#2179304), pg_dump is not going to behave deterministically.  The fact that one file is the reverse of the other is probably just coincidental.

Here is a way that you can do the total comparison including schema and data.

First, compare the schema [using this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178907/postgres-pg-dump-dumps-database-in-a-different-order-every-time/2179608#2179608).

Second, compare the data by dumping it all to a file in an order that will be consistent.  Order is guaranteed by first sorting the tables by name and then by sorting the data within each table by primary key column(s).

The query below generates the `COPY` statements.

```
select
    'copy (select * from '||r.relname||' order by '||
    array_to_string(array_agg(a.attname), ',')||
    ') to STDOUT;'
from
    pg_class r,
    pg_constraint c,
    pg_attribute a
where
    r.oid = c.conrelid
    and r.oid = a.attrelid
    and a.attnum = ANY(conkey)
    and contype = 'p'
    and relkind = 'r'
group by
    r.relname
order by
    r.relname
```

Running that query will give you a list of statements like `copy (select * from test order by a,b) to STDOUT;`  Put those all in a text file and run them through psql for each database and then compare the output files.  You may need to tweak with the [output settings to `COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-copy.html).

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to code an own program for the pg_dump output. Feel free to download [PgDumpSort](http://franke.ms/download/pgdumpsort.jar) which sorts the dump by primary key. With the java default memory of 512MB it should work with up to 10 million records per table, since the record info (primary key value, file offsets) are held in memory.

You use this little Java program e.g. with

```
java -cp ./pgdumpsort.jar PgDumpSort db.sql
```

And you get a file named "db-sorted.sql", or specify the output file name:

```
java -cp ./pgdumpsort.jar PgDumpSort db.sql db-$(date +%F).sql
```

And the sorted data is in a file like "db-2013-06-06.sql"

Now you can create patches using diff

```
diff --speed-large-files -uN db-2013-06-05.sql db-2013-06-06.sql >db-0506.diff
```

This allows you to create incremental backup which are usually way smaller. To restore the files you have to apply the patch to the original file using

```
 patch -p1 < db-0506.diff
```

(Source code is inside of the JAR file)

Comment: Excellent, I just needed a fast way to compare some pre and post south script database dumps for QA purposes. Fast and easy, my thanks. Ran on both dumps, fished through for orphans, instant guarantee we aren't going to cascade away any data.

Answer (score 1):

If

- performance is less important than order
- you only care about the data not the schema
- and you are in a position to recreate both dumps (you don't have to work with existing dumps)

you can dump the data in CSV format in a determined order like this:

```
COPY (select * from your_table order by some_col) to stdout
      with csv header delimiter ',';
```

See [COPY (v14)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-copy.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution to the problem: https://github.com/tigra564/pgdump-sort

It allows sorting both DDL and DML including resetting volatile values (like sequence values) to some canonical values to minimize the resulting diff.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not worth the effort to parse out the dump.

It will be far, far quicker to restore DUMP2 into a temporary database and dump the temporary in the right order.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? You are saying to restore DUMP 2 into a temporary database, but can you clarify on "dump the temporary in the right order."

thanks!

Comment: Oh, you mean to restore DUMP2 into a temporary database, and then dump that database...