# Collating schema changes

Tags: postgresql, flyway

Is it possible for Flyway to monitor a database and generate alter/create statements as they are being done? Rather than submitting alter/create statments to flyway and then allowing it to apply the migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, is not possible to do this with Flyway. The input to Flyway is prepared migrations, in either SQL or Java classes.

To find the required changes you could try a database comparison tool such as requested by this question: [How to check difference between two databases in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804779/how-to-check-difference-between-two-databases-in-postgresql)