# Postgres drift between actual database objects (tables, triggers, sequences, functiions) and an SQL file

Tags: postgresql

I have a master SQL file used to create all the database objects for an application. Is there an application/script to compare what's in the actual database and my SQL file and display the differences?

Answer (score 1):

Comparing SQL files says almost nothing (except if both are identical). There are infinite ways to represent the same DB. And the Postgres version has influence on default settings etc. If both backups are taken with the same version of `pg_dump` from the same version of Postgres on the same server,  then you get closer, but I am not sure both will always be identical event then.

There are tools to compare working installations. So you might create a template DB from the script and compare.

- ["Schema Diff"](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/schema_diff.html) shipped with the free pgAdmin
- [PostgresCompare](https://www.postgrescompare.com/) "identifies database objects that have been new, different or deleted." (Never tried this one myself.)

There are more. See:

- [How to compare data between two databases in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804779/how-to-compare-data-between-two-databases-in-postgresql)